# Kotlin compiler throwing annotation errors after changes made to the build.gradle file

Tags: android, gradle, mvvm, kotlin, androidx

I have made the following changes to my `build.gradle(app)` file.

`apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`

and

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0-alpha01'
    kapt 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.0.0-rc01'

    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-rc01'
    kapt  'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.0.0-rc01'

    implementation 'androidx.paging:paging-runtime:2.1.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

    implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-android:1.7.16'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:1.7.25'
}
```

And now the Kotlin compiler is throwing the following error about my `EntryDAO.kt` and `EntryDatabase.kt` files:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite clear. 
The room’s Delete, Update methods signature has changed. It needs to return void or int.

Edit: I checked again, your gradle file mixed androidx library and pre-AndroidX versions of Lifecycle.

Please follow the link to use the correct library combination: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle

Comment: But they haven't.  I've made no physical change to their code.

Comment: The problem persists.  I migrated everything to androidx (check the edit)